# .NET CORE 3.1 only available for Linux, not Windows?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

Trying to setup an Azure Web App with .NET CORE 3.1
However, when chosing "Code", only **Linux** is available, but not **Windows**. Will this be changed, or is it not possible at all? Do I need a Docker Container?

[image: azure screenshot]

Comment: Have you seen [.NET Core 3.1 Availability on App Service](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/129)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for pointing out. Looks like they rolled it back due to some issues. So we will need to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved at my side, now I can create Azure Web App with .NET CORE 3.1 for windows. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great to know, they are rolling it out

Comment: I don't see it there anymore. Only Linux version is available for .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @CircuitBreaker, this should be rolled back again :(, not stable as of now.

Comment: still not available for windows...

Comment: Hi @BobbyCannon, please see [this](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/129#issuecomment-600593399) for a workaround.